# c# SerialPort DataReceivedHandler not being called for every event.

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am developing a desktop application which interacts with Arduino via SerialPort. 
I want my application to respond every time arduino writes something on the serial port. 
But DataReceivedHandler does not get triggered for all the events. 
Here is the connection code -

```
public static bool connectToArduino()
{
    foreach (string name in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(name);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        if (serialPort.IsOpen == false)
        {
            serialPort.PortName = name;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Openning serial port.");
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.Write(Constants.CONNECT_APP_STRING);
                Console.WriteLine("Written to serial port.");
                string reply = serialPort.ReadLine();
                //string reply = serialPort.ReadTo("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Reply is: " + reply);
                Console.WriteLine("Read from serial port.");
                if (reply == Constants.CONNECT_ACK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected with arduino controller");
                    //serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
                    serialController = serialPort;
                    return true;
                }
                else if (reply+"\n" == Constants.CONNECT_ARDUINO_STRING) {
                    serialPort.WriteLine(Constants.CONNECT_ACK);
                    serialController = serialPort;
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected with arduino controller");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timeout occured.");
                serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR");
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Connection with Arduino failed!");
    return false;
}
```

After this I set the data received handler -

```
SerialComm.serialController.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
```

Now, the problem is that sometimes DataReceivedHandler is not being triggered. 
I am not able to find a pattern in this. It randomly just skips some events. 
Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: this event seems to be not the most reliable. You can find a lot of articles about it if you look for it. What is the frequency of your incoming data? every second?

Comment: Frequency of events is quite erratic, actually this application is a controller for a game involving lasers. So, whenever a user cuts a laser or presses a button an event occurs. So, what is the solution to this problem? If I want a reliable way to get all the events what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find in the remarks:

> The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received. Use the BytesToRead property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer.

If the event is in your case too unreliable to be trusted catch every incoming information from your device, then you could use an extra thread which would run in the background constantly checking the [BytesToRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx) property and/or constantly reading with [ReadExisting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.100).aspx) which is non-blocking.

Comment: Can I simply move entire DataReceived Handler to another thread?
If yes, how would I do that? Also, how do I ensure that thread is not killed of  because I see a lot of "The thread 0x2764 has exited with code 0 (0x0)." in my application logs.

Comment: The DataReceived Handler is on another thread. The event is fired on another thread. What I meant is make a new task after you connect to the device and let it run until your program closes, or the device is disconnected. Unless you don't kill the Task/Thread and is has not finished it's job it will be alive and doing its job :)